# Как реализовать многопоточность в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Суть проблемы надо реализовать чтобы фоном работали одни функции но можно не прерываю их выполнения работать с другой часть кода. Для этого решил реализовать простую программу, которая состоит их двух label и одного button, один label постоянно генерирует новые числа и выводит  в label, а в другой label генерировать числа  по нажатию кнопки. Как это делать?

Вот форма которую создал

[image: Созданная форма]

Вот код который писал с созданным классом

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "examplethreads.h"
#include <QThread>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QThread *thread=new QThread(this);
    ExampleThreads th;
    connect(this,SIGNAL(destroyed()),thread,SLOT(quit()));
    th.moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();

}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{ 
    ui->label_2->setText(QString::number(rand()));

}
```

examplethreads.h

```
#ifndef EXAMPLETHREADS_H
#define EXAMPLETHREADS_H
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThread>
class ExampleThreads:public QObject
{
public:  
    void run();

};

#endif // EXAMPLETHREADS_H
```

examplethreads.cpp

```
#include "examplethreads.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

void ExampleThreads::run()
{
    int a=rand();

}
```

Comment: https://m.habr.com/ru/post/150274/

Comment: Вам именно многопоточность нужна? Просто такой функционал через QTimer реализовать удобнее будет.

Comment: нужно именно, как многопоточность дальше от этого примера буду оталкиваться для работы,  поэтому нужна именно многопоточность

Comment: Я бы использовал `QtConcurrent`

Comment: Варианта в Qt вроде бы два - наследоваться от QThread (ссылку на статью на хабре как это можно правильно сделать в первом комментарии указали) либо использовать модуль `QtConcurrent` с его пулами потоков, задачами `QRunnable` и прочими плюшками. Использование `QtConcurrent` как правило проще, прямое наследование от `QThread` это довольно специчный случай должен быть, например когда вам надо вынести в отдельный поток работу с чем-то и написать свою собственную очередь заданий для этого потока, а не просто выполнить что-то одноразово в фоне (или многоразово)

Comment: Спасибо большое QtConcurrent  помог